# read access database and bind to label

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am having trouble from binding the data retrieved into the label. which i will create a session variable from the label the data is the supplierid of the recent new record
Here the .cs file

```
  protected void InsertSupplier(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
        mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
        + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/IESDatabase.accdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd;

        string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO "
       + " Supplier (sName, sPhone, sAddress, sCompany, sStatus)"
       + " VALUES (@name, @phone, @add, @co, @status)";

        mDB.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLInsert, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtfullname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Phone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtaddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@co", CompanyNameBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", lblStatus.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mDB.Close();
        /*
        OleDbDataReader rdr;
        string strSQLSelect = "SELECT sSupplierId FROM Supplier ORDER BY sSupplierId";
        mDB.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read() == true)
        {
           lblSupplier.Text = rdr["sSupplierId"].ToString();
        }
        Session["sSupplierId"] = (string)lblSupplier.Text;
        */
        MessageBox.Show("Insert New Supplier is successful", "Admin");
        Response.Redirect("Adminpage.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: I see a few issues with your code, but where exactly are you having trouble - the commented code?  How are you implementing MessageBox -- it doesn't work with asp.net...

Comment: Why are you using Access for the data layer of an ASP.NET application?  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: @phoog i am working on a school proj so we can;t use sql server i am aware that access is sort obsolete and troublesome

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg obsolete; maybe, maybe not.  It's certainly not the right tool for a web site.  But as this is a school project, the lack of scalability and robustness are not likely to be a problem for you.